# How to get a $\mathcal{C}$-resolution of $X$ exact?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\Lambda$ be an Artin algebra. We denote by mod$\Lambda$ the category of finitely generated left $\Lambda$-modules. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a full subcategory of mod$\Lambda$. For $X \in $ mod$\Lambda$, we call a complex $A: \cdots \rightarrow C_2 \rightarrow C_1 \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow X$ a right $\mathcal{C}$-resolution of $X$ if $C_i \in \mathcal{C}$ and $\cdots \rightarrow Hom_{\Lambda}(C',C_2) \rightarrow Hom_{\Lambda}(C',C_1) \rightarrow Hom_{\Lambda}(C',C_0) \rightarrow Hom_{\Lambda}(C',X) \rightarrow 0$ is exact for all $C' \in \mathcal{C}$. We write $\mathcal{C}-dim X \leq n$ if $X$ has a right $\mathcal{C}$-resolution with $C_{n+1}=0$.

Now suppose $\mathcal{C}-dim X \leq l$, we can take a right $\mathcal{C}$-resolution $0 \rightarrow C_l \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$. By definition, we know it is a complex. How to get that it is an exact sequence if $\Lambda \in \mathcal{C}$?(If $\Lambda \in \mathcal{C}$, we can get an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$. But I can not make sure that $Hom_{\Lambda}(C',)$ is exact on that sequence.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have $\Lambda \in \mathcal{C}$, you can consider $C' = \Lambda$. Recall that $\text{Hom}_\Lambda(\Lambda, -)$ is naturally equivalent to the forgetful functor $\text{mod}\Lambda \to \text{mod}\mathbb{Z}$. Thus given a $\mathcal{C}$-resolution $0 \rightarrow C_l \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$ you can apply $\text{Hom}_\Lambda(\Lambda, -)$ to find that $0 \rightarrow C_l \rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow C_0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups and since it was a complex to begin with, you are done.